# How to programmatically trigger Quasar QTree lazyLoad event?

Tags: quasar-framework

It's for reloading Quasar QTree nodes children purposes basically.

I managed to trigger the event via the refs but it did not pass the correct event object ({node, done fn, fail fn}) giving following error:

```
const docTree = ref(null)

function onChildrenUpdate(){
  docTree.value.$emit('lazyLoad')
}


Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "node", event is undefined
```

Tried also the `setExpanded` function, as by source code is the only method that triggers `lazyLoad` event but no luck.

There is some meta object which collects data on the loaded state, but as far as I can read there is no access to it from outside the component.
Once children are loaded there is no easy way to reload them after updating externally.

```
function onChildrenUpdate(){
  if (docTree.value.isExpanded(evt)) 
  {
    // in case it has to be collapsed to trigger the event
    docTree.value.setExpanded(evt, false)
  }
  await nextTick() // just in case
  docTree.value.setExpanded(evt, true)
}
```

Has someone had similar problem and can share the solution, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer helped but it doesn't refresh the content if it is lazy loaded. This will also reload the lazy load.

```
function refresh(e, node) {
  delete node.children;
  tree.value.setExpanded(node.id, false);

  nextTick(() => {
    tree.value.setExpanded(node.id, true);
  });
}
```